# How can I emulate Huawei routers HG5xx firmware?

Tags: debugging, firmware, qemu, emulation, firmware-analysis

i want to pentest some HG routers  in a way that i can try every thing without worrying if it would damage the router or not .... and a better view of debugging the actions .